# PyCharm error: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I am using PyCharm for executing my Python programs. Today, I had tried updating all the packages using Project Interpreter. I received the following error in the process:

> error: [Errno 13] Permission denied

[image]

After which none of my Python libraries are shown in Project Interpreter list.

I am using PyCharm Community Edition 2016.2.3 in Mac OS X 10.11.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to give your interpretter root permissions. There is a tutorial [here](http://esmithy.net/2015/05/05/rundebug-as-root-in-pycharm/) on how to do this

Comment: pls can you explain better, I followed the link to the site but still couldn't solve it

Answer (score 2):

For those Windows users, you can change the permission of file operation using git bash. Just open the git bash in that directory and change the file operation using the command `chmod u+rw filename.csv`, where filename is your actual file name, and in the place of CSV, you can give the correct extension of your file.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the shebang if you have it in your code and then try to run it......BTW  this Worked for me.

Comment: My issue was due to a mismatch between the shebang and the interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

The `PermissionError: [errno 13] permission denied` error occurs when you try to access a file from Python without having the necessary permissions. In your case the file (or directory ???) of interest is `/var/folders/2k/_1tccbln53165lgvzvzt3b480000gp/T/tmprqbtrpspycharm-management/setuptools-18.1`. You might want to use `chmod` or `chown` to change access permissions to it.

Answer (score 0):

1. `sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/python`
2. inside the **/etc/sudoers.d/python** you just created enter these details in the given format `<current_username> <hostname> = (root) NOPASSWD: <full path to python>` ie mostly you might have creating a virtual env in pycharm when you start a project. so in that you would find a bin folder. inside which you will find many python virtual interpreters(mention that absolute path ex /home/<project_foldername>/bin/python).
3. anywhere you can create shell script `python-sudo.sh`
4. inside `python-sudo.sh` mention like this `#!/bin/bash sudo <same_path_you_given_in_"/etc/sudoers.d/python"_file> "$@"`
5. Now open your pycharm and project you need to run/debugg the go to `setting > project:projectname > Python Interpreter` Click on Wheel Icon and Then click on "Add"
6. In the new window that popup select Existing Environment > Select the shell script which you created `python-sudo.sh`. Then click OK > and then Click Apply
7. Make sure that on top right side of editor near to green run button `Run/Debug configuration` small drop down menu for your file which you are about to execute/debug click on `Edit Configuration` and the same python interpreter is selected there as well which is `python-sudo.sh`.
8. Now try executing/debugging, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after changing python directory. Then I changed the interpreter setting to a new python directory then 'Run' the code from the Menu and selected 2nd 'Run' option or you can just use the shortcut as Alt+Shift+F10' and a small window appears with your code file name then select the filename which you cant to Run.

This resolved my issue!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RM9ZE.png)