# Error 13 Permission Denied, Pycharm says my SDK seems invalid

Tags: python, pycharm

I am downloading an old school project in preparation for a job interview and I am trying to run it on PyCharm. I originally used an environment of Python 2.7 and although I do still have 2.7 installed I am running Python 3 on current projects.

When I try to open the project, I am getting an alert saying I need to set my configuration. When I tried to add an interpreter, it tells me that my SDK seems invalid and gives me error 13 (permissions denied).

I have tried following the solution suggested here ([PyCharm error: [Errno 13] Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39658864/pycharm-error-errno-13-permission-denied))
to fix the root permissions, and that didn't work. I uninstalled Python 2.7 and tried to remove any references to it, but that hasn't worked either. I am so incredibly confused, any help in the right direction would be very appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pycharm error with pyenv virtualenv: The SDK seems invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66110150/pycharm-error-with-pyenv-virtualenv-the-sdk-seems-invalid)

Comment: Try updating both Pycharm and Git using a fresh installer as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/66979692/5550935. This worked for me