# pycharm error with pyenv virtualenv: The SDK seems invalid

Tags: python, ubuntu, pycharm, virtualenv, pyenv

I am experiencing a problem with pycharm when trying to select as interpreter a python bin created through a pyenv virtualenv.

```
Cannot set up a python SDK 
at Python 3.10 (remote_maax) ($HOME/.pyenv/versions/remote_maax/bin/python).
The SDK seems invalid.
```

I would like to provide more details but pycharm does not provide any additional output.

Even weirder, I am **not** using python 3.10, the virtualenv has been created with python 3.8.5.
The virtualenv also appears to work when activated manually from the shell with `pyenv activate`. I can pip install packages and use them correcly.

I am on a new install of pop os 20.10 (ubuntu), kernel 5.8.0-7642-generic, pyenv 1.2.22, pycharm community 2020.3.3 installed via flatpak.

Does anyone know what can cause this?

Edit: found some more details by launching pycharm from the shell

```
com.jetbrains.python.sdk.InvalidSdkException: Failed to determine Python's sys.path value:
STDOUT: 
STDERR: /home/gio/.pyenv/versions/remote_maax/bin/python3.8: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /home/gio/.pyenv/versions/remote_maax/bin/python3.8)

    at com.jetbrains.python.sdk.PythonSdkType.getSysPathsFromScript(PythonSdkType.java:457)
    at com.jetbrains.python.sdk.PythonSdkType.getSysPath(PythonSdkType.java:439)
    at com.jetbrains.python.sdk.PythonSdkUpdater.evaluateSysPath(PythonSdkUpdater.java:576)
    at com.jetbrains.python.sdk.PythonSdkUpdater.getLocalSdkPaths(PythonSdkUpdater.java:436)
    at com.jetbrains.python.sdk.PythonSdkUpdater.updateLocalSdkPaths(PythonSdkUpdater.java:400)
    at com.jetbrains.python.sdk.PythonSdkUpdater.updateLocalSdkVersionAndPaths(PythonSdkUpdater.java:370)
    at com.jetbrains.python.sdk.PythonSdkUpdater.lambda$updateVersionAndPathsSynchronouslyAndScheduleRemaining$0(PythonSdkUpdater.java:267)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$1.run(CoreProgressManager.java:275)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:962)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.run(CoreProgressManager.java:520)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$new$0(ProgressRunner.java:79)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$3(ProgressRunner.java:235)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:658)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:610)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:65)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:165)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$4(ProgressRunner.java:235)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Unfortunately, I do have libc 2.32 installed, so now I'm even more confused.

```sh
glibc-source/groovy,groovy,now 2.32-0ubuntu3 all [installed]
  GNU C Library: sources

libc6/groovy,now 2.32-0ubuntu3 amd64 [installed]
  GNU C Library: Shared libraries
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to a problem with the flatpack version of Pycharm. I got exactly the same problem (PopOS, Pycharm Professional 2020.3). In the end I replaced the flatpack version with the standalone one (I downloaded Pycharm from Jetbrains site) and work just fine in the exactly the same environment.