# Activate existing venv on pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, python-venv, pyenv

I created venvs for couple diff projects using `python3 -m venv my_project`
Also use `pyenv local version` for managing the python version for each project as needed.

My projects folder looks like this:

```
my-project-one/
my-project-two/
my_project_one/
my_project_two/
```

The ones with hypens are the repo while the ones with underscores are the venv I create for them. (maybe stupid naming scheme but works for me).

I activate the venv with `source ../my_project_one/bin/activate` from within the one I want to work with.

---

It has been great since I was using VSCode. Now I want to use Pycharm and I can't figure out how to make venv work with Pycharm.

In the project interpreter section I can see the two versions under `~/.pyenv/versions/` but that doesn't detect the project dependent requirements I have installed on the venv.

Many articles mentions about adding the python executable unders Scripts folder in venv but there is no such folder in any of mine. (on MacOS)

---

What am I missing here? Did I create the venv incorrectly or following the instruction for the wrong implementation of virtual env because I really don't want to mess with a working setup just for Pycharm.

---

I hope it would at the very least detect the project level libraries and not show unresolved reference for them.

Comment: Are you sure there's no `python.` or `python.exe` in the venv's bin folder?

Comment: @bad_coder coundn't find any executables. Under bin found two alias named `python` and `python3` linked to another bin location on home but unable to make use of them on pycharm in any way.

Comment: That's really strange, when I run the same command on Windows the venv is created with an executable. I suppose pyenv is what's causing that there's a link instead of an executable. And apparently the problem is PyCharm only identifies executabls as interpreters not links.

Comment: There are only [10 questions with the pycharm + pyenv tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyenv+pycharm). In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66110150) it seems to suggest you need to use an additional step of activating by using `pyenv activate` try to using that and afterwards see if the PyCharm can detect the interpreter. If you're really stuck just create a plain venv without pyenv...

Comment: Am not sure if `pyenv activate` is required in my case. I only use it to use a specific version 3.6.9/3.7.11 for my project which I have set at a directory level like `pyenv local 3.7.11`. And PyCharm does properly detect this and uses the correct python interpreter version as set for both projects using pyenv. My issue is that the project specific libraries I have installed on venv is not detected and pycharm asks me to install them.