# Python Folder Permission writing issue

Tags: python, permissions

Could someone please give me some guidance. I am pretty fresh with python.
All I am wanting to do is download zip files from web addresses and save them to a folder.
The same process happens every month so I am trying to automate it.

I have sucessfully download the zip file to a folder of my choice, but when I get python to create the folder I get permission errors. I have read online I can use os.chmod and grant permissions but I cannot figure out how to structure it/ write it so it works

This is what I have so far.

```
import requests, zipfile, io
import os


from datetime import datetime
d = datetime.today().strftime('%b%y') #'Dec20'


newpath = 'L:/Support/Data_load/NativeTitle/{}'.format(d)
if not os.path.exists(newpath):
    os.makedirs(newpath)


os.chmod(newpath , 0o0777)

#chmod -R 777 'L:/Support/Data_load/NativeTitle/{}'.format(d)

print('Folder created in L:\Support\Data_load\NativeTitle')

print('Beginning file download with urllib2...')

url = 'http://www.nntt.gov.au/GeoDocs//ESRI/NTDA_Schedule_Nat_shp.zip'
urllib.urlretrieve(url, newpath)
```

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'L:/Support/Data_load/NativeTitle/Oct21'
```

Comment: Did you run the program with sudo/as admin?

Comment: I have pycharm, i just right click and click run. When i check the folder its a "read only" folder. How do i run it as admin?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyCharm error: \[Errno 13\] Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39658864/pycharm-error-errno-13-permission-denied)

Comment: No i still cannot solve it with that link.